# Alamofire 3.4.0 post call errors on iphone but builds without errors on emulator

Tags: alamofire

The following code build on emulator without error but gives and error when building on iPhone. Xcode updated to the latest release 7.3, Alamofire 3.4.0

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, endPoint,parameters:tokenParams )
              .responseJSON {(response  ) in
        guard let data = response.data else {
                  print("error calling getting data from response")
                  self.delegate?.handleReturnedData("Error! getting data on call to get token" )
    return
    }
```

the error I get on building target iPhone is:

Value of tuple type '(NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, Result)' (aka '(Optional, Optional, Result)') has no member 'data'

Any idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved deleting derived data for the project.
Xcode->Window->Projects->currentProject Derived Data Delete

I discovered this by trial and error or by luck